# remove extra margin at top of img

Tags: html, css

How can I make a img go to the very top of a parent div? There always seems to be an extra px row at the top. In the fiddle, the image shifts down, outside of the div, instead of fitting nicely inside. They have the same height.

In some cases, the img is shorter than the div, in which case it should be centered with equal amounts of parent background above and below it.

http://jsfiddle.net/AqJWa/1/

```
.wrapper{
     width: 140px;
    height: 110px;
    line-height: 110px;
    text-align: center;
    background:red;
    padding:0px;
}


img{
   max-height:110px; 
     max-width:140px; 
     vertical-align: middle;
     margin:0px;
     border:0;  
}

<div class = "wrapper"><img src = 'http://images.tastespotting.com/thumbnails/650041.jpg' alt ="" /></div>
```

Comment: Those are the default padding and margins for p element you'll been to use a reset CSS to eliminate all the default browser styles. A quick fix however would be `p { padding: 0; margin: 0;}`

Comment: @MitchellLayzell that's not the space bothering the OP

Comment: If you find an answer that helps please vote for it AND accept it.

Comment: @koala_dev if hes talking about the 1px from the top on the image, once again a reset CSS would fix it but a quick fix would be `img { display: block;}`

Comment: @Mitchell Layzell Unfortunately it breaks alignment. http://jsfiddle.net/6n9hr/

Comment: @luiges90 then use `margin: 0 auto;` to center it

Comment: What about vertical alignment? (OA's fiddle suggests that it is required). Possibly resort to [Something like this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/exactly-center-an-imagediv-horizontally-and-vertically/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears that there are hidden text (namely, space/newline) in the div.

Try add `font-size:0` for the `.wrapper` div. http://jsfiddle.net/y3mNX/

Answer (score 1):

Reduce line-height: 100px; in the .wrapper class

```
.wrapper{
width: 140px;
height: 110px;
line-height: 100px;
text-align: center;
background:red;
border:0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add     `padding-bottom:5px;` to your  .wrapper css class

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AqJWa/10/)

ie.

```
.wrapper{
  width: 140px;
  height: 110px;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  background:red;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
```